# Best practices for \cite and \citep

Tags: bibliographies, citing, best-practices, bibliographystyle, write

Imagine that `\cite{webb2004oscillations})` and `\citep{webb2004oscillations})` yield, respectively

```
Webb and Owen, 2004
(Webb and Owen, 2004)
```

When writing a paper, what is the best practice to cite this paper under the following contexts:

1. `This leads to an important result, as discussed in \cite{webb2004oscillations}` (without parentheses)
2. `This type of question has been addressed before \citep{webb2004oscillations}` (with parentheses)

This would lead to, respectively

1. "This leads to an important result, as discussed in Webb and Owen, 2004"
2. "This type of question has been addressed before (Webb and Owen, 2004)"

Is this approach correct? Or should we stick to \citep, for example? When reading 1, I feel I should replace "in" with "by", but I am not sure what is the best practice when using `\cite` and `\citep`. I am using `\bibliographystyle{bxv_abbrvnat}`.

Any ideas?

Comment: This is a question of style and different publishers have their own preferences. I think #2 is clear and readable; you're referring to their publication. I agree, I would use "by" in #1, because you're referring to the people, not the publication. Even better, "Webb and Owen (2004) discovered that..." -- which is where commands like `\headlesscite` can be usefull.

Comment: Both types of cites are perfectly correct as far the first is smoothly integrated in the sentence (although is usually better with the year in parenthesis with `\textcite`) whereas `\citep` is only an *addendum*, so the sentence still have full sense without the cite, as you used in the example. A separate issue is if a  journal could have peculiar guidelines at this respect.